# MariaDB Query with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb

In this database

https://www.databasestar.com/sample-database-movies/

[image: ERD]

I would like to make the following query: "List the name and genre of all the actors in the film Brazil".

I make this query:

```
USE movies;

SELECT DISTINCT p.person_name AS 'Nombre', g.gender AS 'Sexo' FROM movie m 
JOIN movie_crew mc ON m.movie_id = mc.movie_id 
JOIN department d ON mc.department_id = d.department_id 
JOIN movie_cast mc2 ON m.movie_id = mc2.movie_id 
JOIN person p ON mc2.person_id = p.person_id 
JOIN gender g ON mc2.gender_id = g.gender_id
WHERE m.title = 'Brazil' AND d.department_name = 'Actors';
```

But no results appear and I don't understand where is my mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. (But if a table is a [mre] base then you will be giving its ERD info in text in code in DDL anyway.)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: You have to dig into the data. I removed the portion of the WHERE clause: `AND d.department_name = 'Actors'` ... and records are found. There happens to NOT be any department_id = 12 (for Actors) in that query combination.

Comment: It's meaningless to consider the 'genre' of actors in this context. Do you mean the 'gender' of characters?

Comment: Hi.

Thanks for the answer and advices. 

Yes, I meant the "gender", not "genre", sorry fot that.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you simplify the schema somewhat.

- Just use simple strings for genre, language_role, keyword, gender, person_name
- Use iso_code in place of country_id
- Perhaps simple abbreviations for department and company
- These *do* need normalizing (as you have don):  person, movie, company, but mostly because there is other stuff in those entities.

That is, get rid of most of the tables in the leftmost and rightmost columns.

Once you have made that change, the error may mysteriously go away.  (And, when you get more data, the queries will run faster.  This does assume you have suitable indexes.)

Comment: This *looks* like an assignment